# Launching Instruments from Xcode on iPhone project with libxml2 fails

Tags: iphone

I get a crash whenever launching an iPhone application that uses libxml2 in Instruments from Xcode. Ideas as to the cause? Ultimately this reason is given:

```
Reason: Incompatible library version: Foundation requires version 10.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 9.0.0
```

Comment: I can't replicate this any more, are you on the absolute latest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed that if you're linking in 3.0 or 3.1 against the SDK-relative version of libxml2.dylib, Instruments works fine.

I'm left believing that the failure under 2.2.1 is simply a bug in that version that must have been a one-off.

Answer (score 0):

For me it happens when I compile a 2.2.1 application for Simulator, then switch Simulator version to 3.0, then launch application from Simulator. My application crashes with the same error you have.

[Update]
Finally, it happends only on simulator, not on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Same behavior here. Instrument crash on simulator but not on iPhone so it's not a solution but at least a work around.

And it works on both simulator and iPhone if i compile on 3.0 SDK